# Building libxml2-2.9.2 for iOS 64 bit

Tags: ios, configure, libxml2, cpu-architecture, arm64

So far I was building libxml2-2.9.2 and previous versions for iOS 32 bits only.
The command I'm using to call configuration script is:

```
./configure --with-debug=no --host=arm-apple-darwin12.5.0 --with-iconv=no --with-zlib=no
```

and this was working just fine.

Now to build it for 64 bit architecture I'm passing:

```
./configure --with-debug=no --host=arm64-apple-darwin12.5.0 --with-iconv=no --with-zlib=no
```

And this is printing out the following errors:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
checking host system type... Invalid configuration `arm64-apple-darwin12.5.0': machine `arm64-apple' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh ./config.sub arm64-apple-darwin12.5.0 failed
```

Do you know how to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to need something like `CCFLAGS="--arch arm64" LDFLAGS="--arch arm64" ./configure --host=arm-apple-darwin12.5.0  blah`.